# Repository of "standard" BDD specs

Tags: bdd, specs

Do you know of any resources or libraries of BDD specs?

For example, almost every web app has a login process. Some "standard" features might be handling of forgotten passwords, reset password, etc.

I'm thinking of something like a code snippet archive of BDD specs so we don't all have to write them from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jean-Paul S. Boodhoo has created a BDD repository of sorts at http://github.com/developwithpassion/developwithpassion.bdd which from the GitHub description is a "BDD Library (MbUnit Based)"